# C# 4.0: Dynamic, Inheriting from DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Let's say I have this:

```
dynamic foo = new Foobar();
```

And I have this:

```
public class Foobar : DynamicObject
{

}
```

The question is, is it possible to override members of `DynamicObject` so that this code:

```
string name = new Foobar().Name
```

Does not throw an `Exception` at run-time? I want to return `default` for `name`'s if `Name` is not a member.

Possible? What do I need to override?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override TryGetMember (and TrySetMember). Classes derived from the DynamicObject class can override this method to specify dynamic behavior for operations such as getting a value for a property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx

Comment: why is when i inherit from dynamicobject like so, i cannot serialize any of the properties? i just get an empty object as a string "{}".

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
class Foobar : DynamicObject 
{
    private object m_object;

    public ExposedObjectSimple(object obj)
    {
        m_object = obj;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(
            InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        //Trying to find appropriate property
        var property = m_object.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (property != null)
        {
            result = (string)property.GetValue(b, null);
            return true;
        }

        result = SomeDefaultName;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override [TryGetMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx).  Just set to always return true, and provide the default if the member does not exist.

Comment: How does Foobar know the default though?

Comment: @CantEatPeanutsDoh: What do you want it to do?  You can make it return anything you want.  If you want the default to be "Fred", just set the value to "Fred" and you're done...

Comment: Hm... This comment contradict to your phrase: "I want to return default for name's if Name is not a member". If Foobar doesn't know default, than who knows? You may return null from Foobar.Name property and lets caller decides what default name is.

Comment: should an object that extends dynamicObject still serialize properly using json.net? it seems if i do JsonConverter.SerializeObject(foo) i just get an empty object in my string "{}"