# Using columns not defined in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dynamic, entity-framework-core, npgsql

ASP .NET Core MVC 5 application runs in different Postgres databases.
Table names are same in all databases.
Base column names and types are same in all databases.

Tables can also contain additional columns added to database after application creation using

ALTER table mytable ADD COLUMN mycol TYPE mytype

commands.

Those additional column names and types are different in different databases.

Custom column list is also stored in table  Datadictionary which contains table name, custom column name and custom column type.

Those columns should displayed to user in view. Views shoud dynamically detect added columns show and allow to change their content.

How to get data from those columns and allow users to change them ?

I'm thinking about 2 possibilities:

1. Create derived from  Varcoltable class which has additional columns, compile
   this class at runtime and pass in to DbContext

Tried

```
   var ctx = new MyDbContext();
   dynamic list = ctx.Varcoltables.FromSqlRaw("select * from varcoltable");

but got error.
```

2. Add property like

   ```
   Dictionary<string,object> CustomColumns;  into base entity class and fill it with custom column values.

    public class Varcoltables : EntityBase { 

     }

     public class EntityBase { 
       public Dictionary<string,object> CustomColumns;
       }
   ```

Tried to use dynamic as child class :

```
class Varcoltable : dynamic { }
```

but got compile error 'Cannot derive from dynamic type'

How to implement this ? Are there some framework source code, documentation or samples how to implement this.

Comment: That is the problem of inherting and deriving. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874875/c-sharp-4-0-dynamic-inheriting-from-dynamicobject) has described this.

Answer (score 0):

FromSqlRaw can only be used to fetch queries of the specific type (whatever Varcoltables is); EF Core doesn't know about your extra columns and therefore can't handle that. More generally, you are trying to both go around EF Core (by adding columns yourself), and to use it to access your modified tables - that's generally not going to work.

Note that EF Core has its own inheritance mapping capabilities, which you can use to achieve something very similar to the above - [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). Is there any reason that doesn't work for you?